# VBA code not running after this one line of code (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba

This has had me stumped for over a week now and I have spent hours of time trying to get it working. Even ChatGPT is stumped.

I have a function which basically inserts a new line at a specific point in a table based on a searched value. It is supposed to insert a blank row to move everything else down, then copy the row above and paste it into the new blank row. Essentially making a duplicate row. I will then have other code to remove certain values from some of the newly pasted in data in the new row.

However, nothing ever runs after this line:

```
tbl.ListRows.Add(lastRowNumber - 2).Range.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
```

It doesn't matter what comes after this line of code, nothing runs, msgboxes, nothing. The row inserts exactly at the correct point, the rest of the code previous to this line works as it should up to this point. The row is inserted and code stops.

Here is the functions full code:

```
Sub InsertNewRowAfterSearchPO()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim tbl As ListObject
Dim rng As Range
Dim searchValue As String
Dim lastRowNumber As Long

' Set the worksheet and table variables
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("POData")
Set tbl = ws.ListObjects("POTable")

' Get the search value from the user
searchValue = InputBox("Enter the value to search for:")

' Find the last matching row based on the search value
Set rng = tbl.DataBodyRange.Columns(2) ' PO Number column
Dim cell As Range
For Each cell In rng.Cells
    If cell.value = searchValue Then
        lastRowNumber = cell.Row
    End If
Next cell

If lastRowNumber = 0 Then
    MsgBox "No matching value found."
Else
    ' Display the identified row number
    MsgBox "The last row number for PO Number '" & searchValue & "' is " & lastRowNumber & "."
    
    ' Insert a new row after the identified row number
    tbl.ListRows.Add(lastRowNumber - 2).Range.Offset(1).Insert Shift:=xlShiftDown
    
    'Run extra code here after insert, yet nothing runs, event this below message box.
    MsgBox "New row inserted beneath the last row with PO Number '" & searchValue & "'."
    
End If 
End Sub
```

Appreciate any ideas as to why the Insert line of code is stopping anything else running even though it inserts successfully.

By the way, if I run the macro manually and it inserts the new line I can then run a second macro to do what I need. But it has to be run one after the other. If I try to call that second function to do the extra business in the above function, it does nothing. For some reason the insert function has to run to completion and fully end, before I can do anything else. But it never ends as the message box is not even displayed.

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue, the code continues when I test it. Do you have any event routine that are triggered (Worksheet_Change or Selection_Change) and could cause that? However, the statement is strange, it will create 2 new rows: One with the `Add`-command and one with the `Insert`-command: Is that what you want?

Comment: That is really odd. Mine creates only the one row. And I don't have any Worksheet_Change functions. Crazy, this one has me completely stumped. I do have a mountain of other code, but nothing that is triggered from any events related to this or onchange.

Comment: It *should* create two, as @FunThomas stated.

Comment: The fact mine is only create one row I guess is a clue as to something else going wrong. Like the msgbox not being displayed I suspect after the row is added the code is stopping which is why I am not seeing the second row or the msgbox. I tried @FaneDuru's suggestion below and the new row is being inserted, but again no additional code will run afterwards. If I call other functions manually afterwards, they work fine, but trying to call a function after the insert automatically does not work either. Still lost on this one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I appreciate all the helpful comments. But I have solved the issue and gutted I didn't try this earlier. Not sure why this fixes the problem, but now the code at least runs. I suspect a bug in Excel that after the insert and with screen updating on code stops. All I did was add...

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    'All code here for the insert
    ' Additional code for after the insert
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

That was it. This solved the issue. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

In order to insert a row (in a table, specific position) and then copy the value above it, please, use the next way:

```
   'your code/declarations...
   Dim insRng As Range
   Set insRng = tbl.ListRows.Add(lastRowNumber - 2, True).Range 'second parameter is AlwaysInsert
   insRng.Value = tbl.ListRows(lastRowNumber - 3).Range.Value 
   'your existing code...
```

Without using a declared range, in some circumstances you need to previously select the inserted row and only after that using to copy the above row content on it. Don't ask me why, because I do not know the answer. It happened to me some times and found this way, not involving the table row selection and clipboard neither...

Comment: Thanks for the helpful explanation. I have tried your suggestion and the code works for inserting the row, but it does not copy the values from above and I am still left with a blank row only. Also, it still appears the msgbox after the insert is still not being displayed. I suspect something else is glitching after the row insert, but for the life of me I cannot figure out what could cause this. I get no errors and everything else seems to run as it should.  Is there a way for force code to run or at least present an error if it is not working?

Comment: FYI: I have tried on Error resume next, on Error Goto xxx etc
I have even enabled in VBA settings, break on all errors to at least try to see what is faulting. But no errors are reported. The function just stops dead after the insert and nothing else runs in that function.

Comment: @MrK Try inserting a code line to select the newly inserted row (`insRng.Select`). Followed by `Selection.Value = tbl.ListRows(lastRowNumber - 3).Range.Value`. This behavior happened to me **only in huge workbooks keeping a lot of code**. Why is that happening? The onest answer is "I don't know"... It looks to be a bug in Excel Application. Selecting it, you 'remember' somehow to Excel about its existence, I think. :) It it still does not solve the problem, please try running the code on a new workbook having in the first sheet only such a tab. I like to believe that you will not have problems